# type 'set<int>' does not provide a subscript operator

Tags: c++, set

```
class Solution {
public:
    int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
        //use set. As in set, element appears only once.

        set<int> s;

        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++) {
            s.insert(nums[i]);
        }

        nums.clear();

        for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++) {

            nums.push_back(s[i]);
        }

        return s.size();
    }
};
```

[https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/solutions/](https://stackoverflow.com)

As you can see above is my solution code for a leetcode problem (I've also given it's link below). I don't seem to see a problem in my code but its giving me error.
Please help.

Comment: `std::set` doesn’t work that way. As always, refer to [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). You should use `for (auto elt : S)` to iterate through the elements of set `S`.

Comment: Given the problem being solved, it's probably easier to pass the input by value, then use something like: `std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end()); return std::unique(nums.begin(), nums.end()) - nums.begin();`

Comment: *"I don't seem to see a problem in my code"* -- Do you see where the compiler tells you the error is located? (There should be an indication of which line and even which character in that line.) Once you see the place where you try to use a subscript operator provided by a `set<int>`, what is the difficulty in understanding "type 'set<int>' does not provide a subscript operator"?

Answer (score 7):

The compiler is correct. A `std::set` does not have a subscript operator. In general, containers with an `operator[]` uses this to provide constant time lookups of elements. In an array, `int arr[10]`, you can use `arr[9]` and get access to the 10:th element just as fast as to the first element, `arr[0]`. This is similar for `std::unordered_map` and `std::map`. You have a *Key* that you can use to lookup a *Value* in approximately the same time independently of which element you look for.

`std::set` is however not such a container. Accessing element `10` in a `std::set` would require that you iterate all the way to the 10:th element. Fortunately, you don't need the subscript operator. Just create the set using the iterators from the `vector` and then assign the result back to the vector:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    std::size_t removeDuplicates(std::vector<int>& nums) {

        // create the set from the values in the vector:
        std::set<int> s(nums.begin(), nums.end());

        // assign the values in the set to the vector:
        nums.assign(s.begin(), s.end());

        return s.size();
    }
};
```

However, reading the actual task reveals something interesting:

> Given an integer array `nums` **sorted in non-decreasing order**, remove the duplicates in-place such that each unique element appears only once. The relative order of the elements should be kept the same.

The fact that it's already sorted makes it tempting to use `std::unique` and `vector::erase` to do this in-place instead of using a `std::set`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

class Solution {
public:
    std::size_t removeDuplicates(std::vector<int>& nums) {
        auto new_end_it = std::unique(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        nums.erase(new_end_it, nums.end());
        return nums.size();
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::map::operator[]` doesn't offer `O(1)` speed lookup, merely `O(log n)`. Which is still better than `O(n)` but possibly worth pointing out.

Comment: @NathanPierson It was a long day and I'm rather tired but rephrased it a bit. That part of the answer was meant to be a sidenote with a motivation for why `set`s don't have an `operator[]` but it's a bit hard to drescribe it correctly while keeping it very short. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) doesn't provide random access via `operator[]`.

As alternatives to using [`std::vector::assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) per [Ted's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75849921/11082165), you can use a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for(const auto i : s) {
   nums.push_back(i);
}
```

or [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
std::copy(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), std::back_inserter(nums));
```